# Using the summation formula for $\pi \cot \pi z$ to sum the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

This question is from my complex analysis assignment and I was unable to solve the problem.

> Using the summation formula for $\pi \cot \pi z$ to sum the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^4$ .

The summation formula $\pi \cot \pi z= 1/z +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^2 -n^2} $ is valid for all non integral z.

but I am not getting any ideas on How it can be done.

SO, Can you please help by doing any 1 series.

Many thanks!

Comment: I would integrate $\pi \cot \pi z/z^2$ and $\pi \cot \pi z/z^4$ round a big square centered on origin whose vertical edges pass through $n\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Or rather $\color{red}{\pm}(n+1/2)$.